# Расчет боевых характеристик в браузерной игре на JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, разработка-игр, математика

Начал писать браузерную игрушку на JS(react/node).

Интересуют алгоритмы расчетов игровой механики.

Например:

1. Есть перс, у него лвл: 1, Сила: 7, броня: 0, уровень жизни 35 и зеркально у противника, они вступают в дуэль. Как рассчитать урон, который один перс нанесет по-другому, есть спец формулы или как это обычно делается в играх?
2. У этих же персонажей прокачаны инстинкт(критический удар), скажем 20, у второго ловкость(уварот от ударов) - 15. Как рассчитывать в зависимости от прокачки перса, вероятность срабатывания критического удара или уварота в бою?
3. Есть 2 персонажа, один 1 лвла и у него 35 жизней, второй 10 лвл и у него 1500 жизней, как организовать восстановление жизней у персов, чтобы не слишком быстро и не слишком медленно, учитывая прокачку навыка регенерация, чем он больше по идее быстрее будет восстанавливаться. Вот вопрос по каким формулам или какому алгоритму считать.

Уверен есть какие то проверенные формулы и алгоритмы подобных расчетов, нужно более менее отбалансированное решение, чтобы бой был честный на любом уровне, а прокачка равномерная.

Comment: Я не знаю, есть ли стандартные формулы, но мне кажется, что все должно зависеть от свойств тех или иных параметров, какую информацию они в себе содержат. Та же "ловкость" - это то такое? Шанс или фиксированное значение? и т.д. Например, в HoMM, превышение атаки над броней дает +5% к урону за каждый пункт. А превышение брони над атакой 2,5% к уменьшению урона, за каждый пункт. Потом высчитывается навыки "Нападения" и "Защиты" - соответственно. Какую стандартную формулу сюда применить?

Answer (score 2):

За основу можете взять механику `DnD`. Она довольно обширная и сложная, но во-первых проверенна временем, во вторых ее можно упростить.

Считать характеристики будем по [формулам](http://dungeon.su/articles/mechanics/26-osnovnye_formuly/)
Например, мы хотим посчитать атаку героя ( *Для упрощения, не будет разделения на атаку ближнего/дальнего боя, типа оружия.* )

> Атака ближнего боя: 1d20 + Мастерство + СИЛ (ЛОВ для изящного оружия)

`1d20` означает, что нужно кинуть кубик `d20` ( кубик, где 20 граней ). В случае кода, нам просто нужна функция, которая будет возвращать целое число от 1 до 20

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}
```

Таким образом, мы можем расчитать как начальные характеристики героя, так и составные при действии

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return () => {
    let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }
}

const randomStat = randomInteger(1, 20);


class Person {
  constructor(random) {
    this.random = random;
    this.strength = this.random(); // сила
    this.agility = this.random(); // ловкость
  }
  stats() {
    return `Сила: ${this.strength}, ловкость: ${this.agility}`
  }
  attack() {
    // формула 1d20 + СИЛА
    return this.random() + this.strength;
  }
}

const a = new Person(randomStat);
console.log(a.stats());
console.log(`Игрок нанес урон: ${a.attack()}`);
console.log(`Игрок нанес урон: ${a.attack()}`);
console.log(`Игрок нанес урон: ${a.attack()}`);
console.log(`Игрок нанес урон: ${a.attack()}`);
```

Соответственно, шанс заклинания можно высчитать по такому же принципу. Но тут лучше сделать ботов по умнее, а не просто рандом. То есть бот должно обрабатывать информацию о своем состоянии, состоянии героя. И от этого принимать решение, но это уже отдельная история